# Angular.js unit testing - trouble mocking $window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I made a simple Angular service to interact with local storage. It has a `has` method that returns true/false, depending on if the key exists in local storage.

```
angular.module("jbLocalStorage", [])
.service("localStorageService", ["$window", function($window){

  this.has = function(key){
    console.log($window); //added to see what $window is referencing in unit test
    if ($window.localStorage.getItem(key) !== null){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
}]);
```

I'm having trouble mocking out $window in my unit test. The unit test still seems to be accessing the global window object and not accessing the mock.

Here is my unit test for this service. I tried to create a mock `$window` object, with a `getItem` function.

```
describe("Has function", function(){
  var localStorageService;

  beforeEach(module('jbLocalStorage'), function($provide){
    $provide.value('$window', {
      localStorage : {
        getItem : function(key){
          if (key === "shape") {return "triangle";} else {return null;}
        },
      },
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function(_localStorageService_){
    localStorageService = _localStorageService_;
  }));

  it("should return true if key is found in local storage", function(){
    expect(localStorageService.has("shape")).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

My test fails, because the test seems to look at the global `window` object and doesn't find "shape", instead of looking in the mock and finding "shape".

I know it's doing this, because the `console.log` line in the service shows that it's still referencing the global `window`object, not the mock.

What am I doing wrong? Why is my mock not working?

Comment: Here is the error that I am receiving:

`Error: Expected false to equal true.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $provide should be injected into the module function.

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/bvsp41yz/

```
describe("Has function", function(){
  var localStorageService;

  beforeEach(module('jbLocalStorage', function($provide){
    $provide.value('$window', {
      localStorage : {
        getItem : function(key){
          if (key === "shape") {return "triangle";} else {return null;}
        },
      },
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_localStorageService_){
    localStorageService = _localStorageService_;
  }));

  it("should return true if key is found in local storage", function(){
    expect(localStorageService.has("shape")).toEqual(true);
    expect(localStorageService.has("wat?")).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent quite a while trying to see the difference between your answer and what I originally wrote. I finally figured out that you removed a parentheses in the first `before each` statement. I had accidentally passed two arguments to `beforeEach`, whereas I should have passed only one `module()' with two arguments inside that.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar and gotten it working. After reviewing my code I believe I have a solution for you.

I think you need to call `$provide` before you call `module('jbLocalStorage')`. I believe that what is happening is that the `$window` service is being injected into your code by the `module` call, then you are modifying the value after it has already been injected.

So this should work:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$window', {
            localStorage : {
                getItem : function(key){
                    if (key === "shape") {return "triangle";} else {return null;}
                },
            },
        });
    });
    module('jbLocalStorage');
});
```

Comment: I just tried it and got: `TypeError: $provide.value is not a function`. It seems that it can't find $provide.

Comment: If I try `  beforeEach(inject(function($provide){'... it also throws an error: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $provideProvider <- $provide`

Comment: My tests are organized a little differently form yours. I changed the example to be closer to how mine are done.